# Cannot convert individual str into Int

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this problem I have parsed log information by splitting it per line and then appending it to a list.  Then I 'cleaned' it by extracting the time stamp, and removing anything that wasn't a number.  Now I am trying to convert each number (which is still a string) into an integer type.

I am still getting an error, and don't really know what I can do to remedy the problem.  I've added the url that contains the time stamp information below:

url: http://projects.bobbelderbos.com/pcc/messages.log

```
import os
import urllib.request

SHUTDOWN_EVENT = 'Shutdown initiated'

# prep: read in the logfile
logfile = #deleted for security reasons
#print(logfile)
urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://projects.bobbelderbos.com/pcc/messages.log', logfile)

with open(logfile) as f:
    loglines = f.readlines()

print(loglines)

def convert_to_datetime(line):

    #takes in the log, separates by line and makes a list per line.
    splitted_list = [i.split() for i in line]
    time_stamp_list = [i[1] for i in splitted_list]
    time_and_date = [i.split('T') for i in time_stamp_list]
    test_parse = [
        i.replace('-', ' ')
            .replace("T", " ")
            .replace(":", " ")
            .split(" ") for i in time_stamp_list
    ]

    print('test parse: ')
    print(test_parse)

    #This returns the necessary values into strings.  Now it's time to convert them into ints, and then a dictionary


    #this is where I am having trouble:
    test_parse_num = [int(i) for i in test_parse]
    print(test_parse_num)
```

Comment: 1. Please post the error message. 2. Why are you fiddling with dates as strings instead of using `datetime` objects?

Comment: Please show sample expected result

Comment: `test_parse_num = [int(j) for i in test for j in i]` it is of type 2D list. It would work but as @JaredSmith suggested you would have to use datetime to deal with this

Comment: Also where is the `convert_to_datetime` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this two solutions need to work:

```
import os
import urllib.request

SHUTDOWN_EVENT = 'Shutdown initiated'

# prep: read in the logfile
logfile = #file that i have from the link
#deleted for security reasons
#print(logfile)
urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://projects.bobbelderbos.com/pcc/messages.log', logfile)

with open(logfile) as f:
    loglines = f.readlines()

print(loglines)

def convert_to_datetime(line):

    #takes in the log, separates by line and makes a list per line.
    splitted_list = [i.split() for i in line]
    time_stamp_list = [i[1] for i in splitted_list]
    time_and_date = [i.split('T') for i in time_stamp_list]
    test_parse = [
        i.replace('-', ' ')
            .replace("T", " ")
            .replace(":", " ")
            .split(" ") for i in time_stamp_list
    ]

    print('test parse: ')
    print(test_parse)

    #This returns the necessary values into strings.  Now it's time to convert them into ints, and then a dictionary

    test_parse_num = []
    #return one list with all the nums:
    for k in test_parse:
        for i in k:
            test_parse_num.append(int(i))
    print(test_parse_num)
```

or:

```
import os
import urllib.request

SHUTDOWN_EVENT = 'Shutdown initiated'

# prep: read in the logfile
logfile = #file that i have from the link
#deleted for security reasons
#print(logfile)
urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://projects.bobbelderbos.com/pcc/messages.log', logfile)

with open(logfile) as f:
    loglines = f.readlines()

print(loglines)

def convert_to_datetime(line):

    #takes in the log, separates by line and makes a list per line.
    splitted_list = [i.split() for i in line]
    time_stamp_list = [i[1] for i in splitted_list]
    time_and_date = [i.split('T') for i in time_stamp_list]
    test_parse = [
        i.replace('-', ' ')
            .replace("T", " ")
            .replace(":", " ")
            .split(" ") for i in time_stamp_list
    ]

    print('test parse: ')
    print(test_parse)

    #This returns the necessary values into strings.  Now it's time to convert them into ints, and then a dictionary

    test_parse_num = []
    #returns a list with lists in it(a list for every log):
    for k in test_parse:
        new = []
        for i in k:

            new.append(int(i))
        test_parse_num.append(new)
    print(test_parse_num)
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you!

Comment: I am now trying to pass this information into a datetime function:


final_prod = [datetime(*i) for i in test_parse_num]
    print(final_prod)

but it returns as:

[datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 3, 23, 24, 31), datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 3, 23, 24, 31), datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 3, 23, 24, 31), ...]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if is this what you're looking for, but there you have it:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> with open('messages.log', 'r') as f:
...     lines = f.readlines()
>>> for line in lines:
...     pieces = line.split(' ')
...     date_format = r'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
...     date = datetime.strptime(pieces[1], date_format)
...     print(date)
...
2014-07-03 23:24:31
2014-07-03 23:24:31
2014-07-03 23:24:31
2014-07-03 23:24:31
```

Comment: I need to find a way to pass this into date time by converting that whole string into a list of numbers.

Comment: can you elaborate? `date` is a [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) object, it has all attributes you can think of about a date and time.